# What is the difference between pgAdmin and Postgres.app?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, postgres.app

After reading official websites as well as conducting Google research I still do not clearly understand how pgAdmin and Postgres.app relate to one another?

For example, I can simultaneously run two different local postgres servers on different ports from both pgAdmin and Postgres.app, which is confusing. I thought that those application depend on one another, but it does not seem so.

Comment: pgAdmin doesn't start a server, it's only a "database viewer". Postgres.app is a server.

Comment: please put some links to the documentation you have read about Postgres.app

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- [Postgres.app](https://postgresapp.com/) is a full-featured PostgreSQL installation packaged as a standard Mac app.  It sets up a PostgreSQL database server on your computer when you install it.
- [PgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/) is graphical user interface administration tool for PostgreSQL.  It is a client tool for working with existing local or remote PostgreSQL servers.  It does **not** include a PostgreSQL database server.